# Rails Mailboxer add column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration, mailboxer

I'd like to add a column to the Mailboxer migration, but have no idea how to do that. Simply generating the migration and migrating is not enough. Anyone with similar experience?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify already applied migration.

There is two options how to add collumn in this situation, create create new migration or [rollback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#rolling-back) to step before migration that you're changing, edit it and apply it again.

First one is better.

Also, there is step by step installation guide for [Mailboxer on GitHub](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer#installation).

Comment: as stated above, generating a migration (i.e. add_field_to_conversations) does not work; that's where I'm stuck, no idea how to add a migration

Comment: Can you compare your schema.rb before and after it, if there was no errors after applying migrations you should have changes in schema.rb.

Comment: my point is that by creating a migration ("rake g migration add_field_to_conversations") creates the migration, but it is nowhere to be seen (the conversation does not have the field attribute). And I have no idea how to set the params of the model.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

rails g migration add_fields_to_mailboxer_notification example:s